# How to create a Marquee for Circular Progress Bar and fill only the gray area of bar using C# and WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, progress-bar

I have created a custom circular progress bar, as shown below:

[image]

Using the following code:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApp1.SpinnerProgressBar"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
            <Viewbox>
            <Canvas Width="100" Height="100">
                <!-- Base Spinner -->
            <Path Stroke="LightGray" StrokeThickness="3" Fill="LightGray"
                      Data="M 0 100 a 100,100 0 1 1 200,0 
                                    a 100,100 0 1 1 -200,0 
                            M 30 100 a 70,70 0 1 1 140,0
                                     a 70,70 0 1 1 -140,0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" />

            <!-- Loader Spinner "M 0 100 a 100,100 0 0 1 100,-100 v 30 a 70,70 0 0 0 -70,70" -->

            <Path Fill="Gold" Data="M 0 100 a 100,100 0 0 1 100,-100 v 30 
                                              a 70,70 0 0 0 -70,70" RenderTransformOrigin="1,1" >
                <Path.RenderTransform>
                    <TransformGroup>
                        <ScaleTransform/>
                        <SkewTransform/>
                        <RotateTransform Angle="0"/>
                        <TranslateTransform/>
                    </TransformGroup>
                </Path.RenderTransform>
            </Path>
        </Canvas>
    </Viewbox>

</UserControl>
```

with Mimicing Marquee behaviour, I would just need to do the binding to `<RotateTransform Angle="0"/>` (If I am not mistaken). However, I am stuck on the part of how to create a full progressbar when there is a case say like successful connection to the database and with marquee when still trying to connect. How can I do the full progressbar part? If there is a tutorial/video that would explain how to do it I would appreciate it.

***Edit 1:***
I have tried the following code thanks to @EldHasp where I have done the following:

**SpinnerProgressBar.xaml**

```
<UserControl x:Class="SpinnerProgress.SpinnerProgressBar"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SpinnerProgress"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800"
             xmlns:rpb="clr-namespace:SpinnerProgress.spinnerprogressbar">

    <!-- Spinner Design -->
        <!-- Use the text document about the path commands in Data. -->
        <Viewbox>
            <Grid>
                <!-- Arc Movement requirements: (Size, (RotatingAngle, isLargeArc, SweepDirection), Coordinates[End-points]) -->
                <Canvas Width="100" Height="100">
                    <Path Stroke="LightGray" StrokeThickness="3" Fill="LightGray" Panel.ZIndex="2"
                          Data="M 0 100 a 100,100 0 1 1 200,0 
                                        a 100,100 0 1 1 -200,0 
                                M 30 100 a 70,70 0 1 1 140,0
                                         a 70,70 0 1 1 -140,0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" />
                    <!-- Arc Movement requirements: (Size, (RotatingAngle, isLargeArc, SweepDirection), Coordinates[End-points]) -->
                    <!-- Loader Spinner "M 0 100 a 100,100 0 0 1 100,-100 v 30 a 70,70 0 0 0 -70,70" -->
                    <Path x:Name="progressPath" Fill="Gold" RenderTransformOrigin="1,1">
                        <Path.Data>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{x:Static local:ProgressBarToGeometryConverter.Instance}">
                                <Binding Path="Value" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=local:SpinnerProgressBar}"/>
                                <Binding Path="Maximum" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=local:SpinnerProgressBar}"/>
                                <Binding Path="Minimum" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=local:SpinnerProgressBar}"/>
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </Path.Data>
                    </Path>
                </Canvas>
            </Grid>
        </Viewbox>
    
</UserControl>
```

**Code Behind SpinnerProgressBar**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace SpinnerProgress
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for SpinnerProgressBar.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class SpinnerProgressBar : UserControl
    {
        public SpinnerProgressBar()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void StartMarqueeAnimation()
        {
            // Create a double animation to rotate the Path (marquee effect)
            var rotationAnimation = new DoubleAnimation
            {
                To = 360, // Rotate a full circle (360 degrees)
                Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), // Adjust the duration as needed
                RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever // Keep repeating the animation
            };

            progressPath.RenderTransform = new RotateTransform(); // Add a RotateTransform
            progressPath.RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(1, 1); // Set the rotation origin to the center

            // Begin the rotation animation
            progressPath.RenderTransform.BeginAnimation(RotateTransform.AngleProperty, rotationAnimation);
        }
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="SpinnerProgress.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SpinnerProgress"
        xmlns:spb="clr-namespace:SpinnerProgress.spinnerprogressbar"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">

    <Window.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:5"
                                     To="10"
                                     Storyboard.TargetName="Spinner"
                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Value"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Window.Triggers>

    <Grid>
        <spb:SpinnerProgressBar x:Name="Spinner" Maximum="10" Minimum="-10" Value="-10" Height="100" Width="100" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Grid>
    
</Window>
```

**Converter.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Markup;
using System.Windows.Media;
using static System.Math;

namespace SpinnerProgress.spinnerprogressbar
{
    public class SpinnerProgressBar : RangeBase
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Value", typeof(double), typeof(SpinnerProgressBar), new PropertyMetadata(0.0));
        public static readonly DependencyProperty MaximumProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Maximum", typeof(double), typeof(SpinnerProgressBar), new PropertyMetadata(0.0));
        public static readonly DependencyProperty MinimumProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Minimum", typeof(double), typeof(SpinnerProgressBar), new PropertyMetadata(0.0));

        public double Value
        {
            get { return (double)GetValue(ValueProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ValueProperty, value); }
        }

        public double Maximum
        {
            get { return (double)GetValue(MaximumProperty); }
            set { SetValue(MaximumProperty, value); }
        }

        public double Minimum
        {
            get { return (double)GetValue(MinimumProperty); }
            set { SetValue(MinimumProperty, value); }
        }

        static SpinnerProgressBar()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(SpinnerProgressBar), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(SpinnerProgressBar)));
        }
    }

    [ValueConversion(typeof(SpinnerProgressBar), typeof(Geometry))]
    public class ProgressBarToGeometryConverter : IMultiValueConverter
    {
        private static readonly double valPI = 2 * PI;
        public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            double min = (double)values[0];
            double max = (double)values[1];
            double value = (double)values[2];

            double angle = (value - min) / (max - min);
            angle *= valPI;
            if (!double.IsNormal(angle))
                return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;

            double cos = Cos(angle);
            double sin = Sin(angle);
            double x1 = 100 * cos + 100;
            double y1 = 100 * sin + 100;
            double x2 = 70 * cos + 100;
            double y2 = 70 * sin + 100;

            StreamGeometry sg = new();
            sg.FillRule = FillRule.EvenOdd;

            using StreamGeometryContext sgc = sg.Open();
            if (value >= max)
            {
                sgc.BeginFigure(new Point(200, 100), true, true);
                sgc.ArcTo(new Point(0, 100), new Size(100, 100), 0, false, SweepDirection.Clockwise, true, false);
                sgc.ArcTo(new Point(200, 100), new Size(100, 100), 0, false, SweepDirection.Clockwise, true, false);
                sgc.LineTo(new Point(170, 100), true, false);
                sgc.ArcTo(new Point(30, 100), new Size(070, 070), 0, false, SweepDirection.Counterclockwise, true, false);
                sgc.ArcTo(new Point(170, 100), new Size(070, 070), 0, false, SweepDirection.Counterclockwise, true, false);
            }
            else
            if (angle < PI)
            {
                sgc.BeginFigure(new Point(200, 100), true, true);
                sgc.ArcTo(new Point(x1, y1), new Size(100, 100), 0, false, SweepDirection.Clockwise, true, false);
                sgc.LineTo(new Point(x2, y2), true, false);
                sgc.ArcTo(new Point(170, 100), new Size(070, 070), 0, false, SweepDirection.Counterclockwise, true, false);
            }
            else
            {
                sgc.BeginFigure(new Point(200, 100), true, true);
                sgc.ArcTo(new Point(x1, y1), new Size(100, 100), 0, true, SweepDirection.Clockwise, true, false);
                sgc.LineTo(new Point(x2, y2), true, false);
                sgc.ArcTo(new Point(170, 100), new Size(070, 070), 0, true, SweepDirection.Counterclockwise, true, false);
            }
            return sg;
        }

        public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public ProgressBarToGeometryConverter() { }
        public static ProgressBarToGeometryConverter Instance { get; } = new();
    }

    [MarkupExtensionReturnType(typeof(ProgressBarToGeometryConverter))]
    public class ProgressBarToGeometryExtension : MarkupExtension
    {
        public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            return ProgressBarToGeometryConverter.Instance;
        }
    }
}
```

It does not seem to work. I was thinking of adding the Marquee into the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example of a round ProgressBar.

Custom Control and Converter:

```cs
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Markup;
using System.Windows.Media;
using static System.Math;

namespace Core2023.RoundProgressBar
{
    public class RoundProgressBar : RangeBase
    {
        static RoundProgressBar()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(RoundProgressBar), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(RoundProgressBar)));
        }
    }

    [ValueConversion(typeof(ProgressBar), typeof(Geometry))]
    public class ProgressBarToGeometryConverter : IMultiValueConverter
    {
        private static readonly double valPI = 2 * PI;
        public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            double min = (double)values[0];
            double max = (double)values[1];
            double value = (double)values[2];

            double angle = (value - min) / (max - min);
            angle *= valPI;
            if (!double.IsNormal(angle))
                return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;

            double cos = Cos(angle);
            double sin = Sin(angle);
            double x1 = 100 * cos + 100;
            double y1 = 100 * sin + 100;
            double x2 = 70 * cos + 100;
            double y2 = 70 * sin + 100;


            string data;
            if (angle < PI)
            {
                data = @$"
M200,100
A100,100 0 0 1 {x1.ToString(culture)},{y1.ToString(culture)}
L{x2.ToString(culture)},{y2.ToString(culture)}
A070,070 0 0 0 170,100
z";
            }
            else
            {
                data = @$"
M200,100
A100,100 0 1 1 {x1.ToString(culture)},{y1.ToString(culture)}
L{x2.ToString(culture)},{y2.ToString(culture)}
A070,070 0 1 0 170,100
z";
            }
            return Geometry.Parse(data);
        }

        public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        private ProgressBarToGeometryConverter() { }
        public static ProgressBarToGeometryConverter Instance { get; } = new();
    }

    [MarkupExtensionReturnType(typeof(ProgressBarToGeometryConverter))]
    public class ProgressBarToGeometryExtension : MarkupExtension
    {
        public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            return  ProgressBarToGeometryConverter.Instance;
        }
    }
}
```

Theme Generic.xaml:

```xml
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Core2023"
    xmlns:rpb="clr-namespace:Core2023.RoundProgressBar">


    <Style TargetType="{x:Type rpb:RoundProgressBar}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type rpb:RoundProgressBar}">
                    <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                        <Geometry x:Key="round">
                            M 0 100 a 100,100 0 1 1 200,0
                            a 100,100 0 1 1 -200,0
                            M 30 100 a 70,70 0 1 1 140,0
                            a 70,70 0 1 1 -140,0</Geometry>
                    </ControlTemplate.Resources>
                    <Grid>
                        <!-- Base Spinner -->
                        <Path Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                              Data="{StaticResource round}"/>
                        <Path Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" StrokeThickness="3"
                              Data="{StaticResource round}" Panel.ZIndex="2"/>

                        <!-- Loader Spinner "M 0 100 a 100,100 0 0 1 100,-100 v 30 a 70,70 0 0 0 -70,70" -->

                        <Path Fill="Gold">
                            <Path.Data>
                                <MultiBinding Converter="{rpb:ProgressBarToGeometry}">
                                    <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=rpb:RoundProgressBar}" Path="Minimum"/>
                                    <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=rpb:RoundProgressBar}" Path="Maximum"/>
                                    <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=rpb:RoundProgressBar}" Path="Value"/>
                                </MultiBinding>
                            </Path.Data>
                        </Path>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Window with an example of use and animation of the Value property:

```xml
<Window x:Class="Core2023.RoundProgressBar.RoundProgressBarWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Core2023.RoundProgressBar"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="RoundProgressBarWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:5"
                                     To="10"
                                     Storyboard.TargetName="rpb"
                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Value"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Window.Triggers>
    <Grid>
        <local:RoundProgressBar x:Name="rpb"
                                Maximum="10" Minimum="-10" Value="-10"
                                BorderBrush="Aqua"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The Value property can be bound to the ViewModel or set in any other way. Progress will be displayed correctly.

**P.S.** This is an improved version of the converter using StreamGeometry.

```cs
    [ValueConversion(typeof(ProgressBar), typeof(Geometry))]
    public class ProgressBarToGeometryConverter : IMultiValueConverter
    {
        private static readonly double valPI = 2 * PI;
        public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            double min = (double)values[0];
            double max = (double)values[1];
            double value = (double)values[2];

            double angle = (value - min) / (max - min);
            angle *= valPI;
            if (!double.IsNormal(angle))
                return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;

            double cos = Cos(angle);
            double sin = Sin(angle);
            double x1 = 100 * cos + 100;
            double y1 = 100 * sin + 100;
            double x2 = 70 * cos + 100;
            double y2 = 70 * sin + 100;

            StreamGeometry sg = new();
            sg.FillRule = FillRule.EvenOdd;

            using StreamGeometryContext sgc = sg.Open();
            if (value >= max)
            {
                sgc.BeginFigure(new Point(200, 100), true, true);
                sgc.ArcTo(new Point(0, 100), new Size(100, 100), 0, false, SweepDirection.Clockwise, true, false);
                sgc.ArcTo(new Point(200, 100), new Size(100, 100), 0, false, SweepDirection.Clockwise, true, false);
                sgc.LineTo(new Point(170, 100), true, false);
                sgc.ArcTo(new Point(30, 100), new Size(070, 070), 0, false, SweepDirection.Counterclockwise, true, false);
                sgc.ArcTo(new Point(170, 100), new Size(070, 070), 0, false, SweepDirection.Counterclockwise, true, false);
            }
            else
            if (angle < PI)
            {
                sgc.BeginFigure(new Point(200, 100), true, true);
                sgc.ArcTo(new Point(x1, y1), new Size(100, 100), 0, false, SweepDirection.Clockwise, true, false);
                sgc.LineTo(new Point(x2, y2), true, false);
                sgc.ArcTo(new Point(170, 100), new Size(070, 070), 0, false, SweepDirection.Counterclockwise, true, false);
            }
            else
            {
                sgc.BeginFigure(new Point(200, 100), true, true);
                sgc.ArcTo(new Point(x1, y1), new Size(100, 100), 0, true, SweepDirection.Clockwise, true, false);
                sgc.LineTo(new Point(x2, y2), true, false);
                sgc.ArcTo(new Point(170, 100), new Size(070, 070), 0, true, SweepDirection.Counterclockwise, true, false);
            }
            return sg;
        }

        public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        private ProgressBarToGeometryConverter() { }
        public static ProgressBarToGeometryConverter Instance { get; } = new();
    }
```

**Errors in "Edit 1"**

1. "class SpinnerProgressBar : UserControl" - this class is superfluous. Remove it.
2. In the class "class SpinnerProgressBar : RangeBase" there is no need to declare the Minimum, Maxmimum and Value properties. These properties are already declared in the base class "RangeBase".
3. The class "SpinnerProgressBar : RangeBase" is a Custom Control and you need to declare a theme for it. The default theme is the file "Themes/Generic.xaml".

You can download the full working project from here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lUpKDHz0QQ_NoFEXeXeWBcBMVgj8WZhW/view?usp=drive_link

Comment: The converter code looks odd. Why parse a Geometry from a string when you could  directly create a PathGeometry or StreamGeometry? And why should it be a MarkupExtension (without any explanation of what that is) when it could simply be declared inline or as XAML resource?

Comment: @Clemens , The example was created “in a hurry” and with strings it is easier and faster to debug the code. I agree with you that it is possible to do it more optimally. In this case, I think the best would be to use StreamGeometry.

Comment: *“in a hurry”* - well, fix that to make it a good answer. There is nothing worse than answers written in a hurry that let bad code survive. Imagine a newbie that sees this and gets the impression that this is the way to create Geometries.

Comment: @Clemens , I've updated my answer to take into account your comment.

Comment: @EldHasp Thank you for the answer. I just have a question, where would I find an explanation for the calculation that you sent? (part with the Converter)

Comment: @WDpad159 Well, it's just geometry. School course. I don’t even know what to explain there. The ring is in the positive quarter. The outer diameter is 100, the inner diameter is 70. The starting points for the arc segments are, respectively, (200, 100) and (170, 100). The end points are calculated using the sine and cosine of the angle. The angle is calculated as a fraction of the range between the maximum and minimum.

Comment: @EldHasp  Thank you for the code and the explanation. I will read about the arc calculation and try to understand parts of the if-else statements about the StreamGeometryContext. I would assume that they follow the steps like in `Data="M 0 100 a 100,100 0 0 1 100,-100 v 30 
                                              a 70,70 0 0 0 -70,70"` but more as step by step.

Comment: @EldHasp I have modified my code but I can't seem to get it to work. I was trying the following approach in Edit 1. Can you have a look at my code and point out what could be the issue?

Comment: @WDpad159 Read the update to my answer.

Comment: @EldHasp thank you for your reply and explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Doing the rotate animation for *Marquee* effect is pretty easy, just need to animate the `RenderTransform.RotateTranform` property.

You can achieve it like so. Here's declaration of the `Storyboard`, with some extra effect for the rotation, and example trigger by `IsMouseOver` on selected `Path`.

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Key="SpinStoryboardSpinning" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Path.RenderTransform).(RotateTransform.Angle)">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="90"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="180"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="450">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                    <QuadraticEase EasingMode="EaseInOut"/>
                </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Path Fill="Gold"
      Data="M 0 100 a 100,100 0 0 1 100,-100 v 30 a 70,70 0 0 0 -70,70"
      RenderTransformOrigin="1,1">
    <Path.RenderTransform>
            <RotateTransform Angle="90"/>
    </Path.RenderTransform>
    <Path.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Path}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Trigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource SpinStoryboardSpinning}"/>
                    </Trigger.EnterActions>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Path.Style>
</Path>
```

But in order to create a full progress bar, it's more complext task.

First of all you need to have control over the created `Storyboards`, ie stop and start them when needed. Also for the `ProgressBar` itself, I'd recommend to start by deriving from the `ProgressBar` Control and style it as you wish.

Good start would be to create first, *standard*, but styled `ProgressBar` based on this example from MSDN https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/progressbar-styles-and-templates?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response. I will have a look at the animation but can it also be done through the code behind for the Marquee behaviour? with regards to filling the bar, you mean for the start and stop for like changing from Marquee to the filling the path? I will have a look at the link that you sent

Comment: I would use VisualStates as described in the example I posted, and on Intermediate State show Marquee, while on Determinate show actual progress. About Storyboards here's good article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/graphics-multimedia/storyboards-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

Comment: Thank you, the code works for the marquee. I will read about the storyboard and see how I can implement that to the progressbar.